# How can i solve Possible Missing firmware error

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, acer, amdgpu, firmware

```
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vega10_cap.bin for module amdgpu
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_cap.bin for module amdgpu
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_cap.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/psp_13_0_7_sos.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/psp_13_0_0_sos.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_cap.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_2_imu.bin for module amdgpu
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_1_imu.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_0_imu.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_2_rlc.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_2_mec.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_2_me.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_2_pfp.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_1_rlc.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_1_mec.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_1_me.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_1_pfp.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_0_toc.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_0_rlc.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_0_mec.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_0_me.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_0_pfp.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sdma_6_0_2.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sdma_6_0_1.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sdma_6_0_0.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes1.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_2_mes1.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_2_mes.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_1_mes1.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_1_mes.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_0_mes1.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_0_mes.bin for module amdgpu
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vcn_4_0_4.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vcn_4_0_0.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/smu_13_0_7.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/smu_13_0_0.bin for module amdgpu 
        Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/discovery_wifi.bin for module amdgpu
```

ihave an Acer Aspire 5 A515-46-R3UB , AMD Ryzen 3 3350U, 4GB DDR4, 128GB NVMe SSD, WiFi 6. it came with windows 11 and i used ventoy kubuntu 20.10 iso and upoun updating it returned the errors below. after several attempts and failures i eventually resolved the terminal errors.
my solutionwas as follows.

```
sudo apt install git
cd ~/Documents && git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
sudo cp ~/Documents/linux-firmware/amdgpu/* /lib/firmware/amdgpu && sudo update-initramfs -k all -u -v
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
reboot
```

although the errors are no longer being returned my screen is now fuzzy when i open the lid just for a brief second before it returns to normal. its not damaged as i installed windows 10 to see if the issue was present with window OS and it worked normally. so i reinstalled Kubuntu and again resolved missing firmware issue but the screen still flashes fuzzy when being opened regardless if its been in sleep state or just closed and reopened. i imagine it must be a rendering bug with the GPU firmware.   Any ideas?